# Bind class properties from string in c#

Tags: c#, reflection, model-binding

I have a string like "dataSource=ReportDataSource;storedProcedure=GetUserEmails;tableName=Users".
Is there a way to bind the class properties from this type of string. I have a class with all 3 properties dataSource,storedProcedure and tableName.

Comment: Yes we can bind it, Can you add class definition? Can you show us what you tried so far

Comment: Do you want a class that contains "ReportDataSource", "GetUserEmails" and "Users" in the relevant properties, or do you want a list of objects that are bound from the _results_ of executing that SP? In the first case, look at the ConnectionStringBuilder class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your target class looks like this:

```
    public class Target
    {
        public string DataSource {get;set;}
        
        public string StoredProcedure {get;set;}
        
        public string TableName {get;set;}
    }
```

Here's a simple way to do it:

```
// That's your source string
var source = "dataSource=ReportDataSource;storedProcedure=GetUserEmails;tableName=Users";

// Using a couple of replaces and add `{"` at the start and `"}` at the end, 
// convert your source string to json:
var json = "{\"" + source.Replace("=", "\":\"").Replace(";", "\",\"") + "\"}";

// Deserialize
var target = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Target>(json);
```

Note: If your string already contains `\"` inside - you need to escape it:

```
var json = "{\"" + source.Replace("\"", "\\\"").Replace("=", "\":\"").Replace(";", "\",\"") + "\"}";
```

You can see a live demo on [<kbd>Restester.</kbd>](https://rextester.com/JSS71999)

Comment: Glad to help ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use linq instead of the loops, but temporarily this should work:

```
string s = "dataSource=ReportDataSource;storedProcedure=GetUserEmails;tableName=Users";
var split1 = s.Split(';');
var props = new Dictionary<string, string>();
foreach(var ss in split1)
{
    var splitProperty = ss.Split('=');
    props.Add(splitProperty[0], splitProperty[1]);
}
var newDbCon = new dbCon();
var classType = typeof(dbCon);
foreach(var p in props)
{
    classType.GetProperty(p.Key).SetValue(newDbCon, p.Value);
}
```

And the class:

```
class dbCon
    {
        public string dataSource { get; set; }
        public string storedProcedure { get; set; }
        public string tableName { get; set; }
    }
```